# Xamarin.Forms Shell - Cannot use ShellContent unless within a <Tab>?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've downloaded and opened the Xamarin.Forms Shell example project [Xanimals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) from Microsoft, but it's throwing build errors from AppShell.xaml.

The errors are:

**Error    XLS0503 A value of type 'ShellContent' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'.   Xaminals    AppShell.xaml   135**

**Error    XLS0503 A value of type 'MenuItem' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'.   Xaminals    AppShell.xaml   158**

**Invalid type: expected type is 'ShellSection', actual type is 'ShellContent'.**

**Invalid type: expected type is 'ShellSection', actual type is 'MenuItem'.**

I originally found this problem when I created a new Xamarin Shell application and followed Microsoft's corresponding guide, wherein their example code describes putting some ShellContent elements directly under a FlyoutItem in the app's AppShell.xaml file.

Here's the relevant code section from the Microsoft Xanimals sample project:

```
<FlyoutItem Route="animals"
            Title="Animals"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="Domestic"
         Route="domestic"
         Icon="paw.png">
        <ShellContent Route="cats"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Cats"
                      Icon="cat.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Dogs"
                      Icon="dog.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <ShellContent Route="monkeys"
                  Style="{StaticResource MonkeysShell}"
                  Title="Monkeys"
                  Icon="monkey.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="elephants"
                  Style="{StaticResource ElephantsShell}"
                  Title="Elephants"
                  Icon="elephant.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ElephantsPage}" />  
    <ShellContent Route="bears"
                  Style="{StaticResource BearsShell}"
                  Title="Bears"
                  Icon="bear.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BearsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<ShellContent Route="about"
              Style="{StaticResource AboutShell}"
              Title="About"
              Icon="info.png"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}" />

<MenuItem Text="Random"
          Icon="random.png"
          Command="{Binding RandomPageCommand}" />
<MenuItem Text="Help"
          Icon="help.png"
          Command="{Binding HelpCommand}"
          CommandParameter="https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell" />
```

Here is a screenshot of the above code, with Intellisense underlining the problem areas:

[image: xanimals_sample]

For reference, I've tried updating the Xamarin.Forms NuGet reference to every version between 4.0.0.425677 and 4.1.0.673156, still no luck. 
I'm using **Visual Studio Professional 2019, version 16.1.2** and **.NET Framework version 4.7.03056**

Is Microsoft's Xanimals sample code wrong, or is there something I'm missing?
Again, I'm using the Xanimals sample code right out of the box, nothing has been changed.

EDIT:
Microsoft's own Shell example explains the following:

> ShellContent, which represents the ContentPage objects in your application. **Every ShellContent object is a child of a Tab object.** When more than one ShellContent object is present in a Tab, the objects will be navigable by top tabs.

Yet, despite the assertion that Every ShellContent object is a child of a Tab object, their code sample seems to contradict this rule (in the screenshot, the ShellContents that are outside of the Tab, and also the ones outside of the FlyoutItem).

Comment: I've ran into the same issue. thus it is an Intelissence problem, since the project compiles and runs smoothly

Comment: How did you get your application to run with the errors? My projects can build fine, but the deploy fails because of these errors.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue,i try the methods below:

1. clean the solution and rebuild it.
2. delete the `obj` and `bin` files and restart the visual studio.

Both methods ignore warnings and run it.it works,maybe the issue will be fixed later。

Comment: @JakeSteed What is strange is that I only gave warning and did not give an error